# How build combinations with maximum sum, that contains only from one digit per row and their total prices must be less then 15

Tags: javascript, matrix

How build combinations with maximum sum along the column, that contains only from one digit per row and their total prices must be less then 15

I need to find maximum sum along the column, each column has a price. Maximum allowable price 15$, but the price can be repeated, example [4, 4, 3, 2, 2]. Each row has 1 field with null.
The result should be an array of 5 values with maximum sum.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K519y.jpg)

I tried doing like this:

```js
    //const g1 = [89, 85, 76, 65, 60];
    //const g2 = [85, 83, 72, 63, 35];
    //const f1 = [84, 78, 64, 56, 46];
    //const f2 = [83, 76, 62, 55, 45];
    //const y1 = [85, 79, 61, 50, 43];
    // 60 + 72 + 78 + 55 + 85 = 337
    console.log(76 + 85 + 56 + 76 + 43)
    const g1 = [89, 85, null, 65, 60];
    const g2 = [null, 83, 72, 63, 35];
    const f1 = [84, 78, 64, null, 46];
    const f2 = [83, null, 62, 50, 45];
    const y1 = [85, 79, 61, 50, null];
    
    const getAllIndexes = (arr, val) => {
        let indexes = [], i = -1;
        while ((i = arr.indexOf(val, i+1)) != -1){
            indexes.push(i);
        }
        return indexes;
    }
    
    const arrayAllMaxIndexes = (array) => {
        return getAllIndexes(array, Math.max.apply(null, array));
    }
    
    const arrayAllMinIndexes = (array) => {
        return getAllIndexes(array, Math.min.apply(null, array));
    }
    
    const choosedIndexes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      const row = [g1[i], g2[i], f1[i], f2[i], y1[i]].map((item, index) => {
        if (choosedIndexes.includes(index)){
          return 0;
        } else {
          return item;
        }
      });
    
      const maxIndexes = arrayAllMaxIndexes(row);
      console.log(maxIndexes)
      let maxIndex = null;;
      if (maxIndexes.length > 1) {
        const nextValues = [];
        maxIndexes.forEach((index) => {
            switch(index) {
              case 0: 
                nextValues.push(g1[i + 1] ? g1[i + 1] : g1[i - 1]);
                break;
              case 1: 
                nextValues.push(g2[i + 1] ? g2[i + 1] : g2[i - 1]);
                break;  
              case 2: 
                nextValues.push(f1[i + 1] ? f1[i + 1] : f1[i - 1]);
                break;    
              case 3: 
                nextValues.push(f2[i + 1] ? f2[i + 1] : f2[i - 1]);
                break;    
              case 4: 
                nextValues.push(y1[i + 1] ? y1[i + 1] : y1[i - 1]);
                break;     
            }
        });
        const newMinIndexes = arrayAllMinIndexes(nextValues);
        maxIndex = maxIndexes[newMinIndexes[0]]
      } else {
        maxIndex = maxIndexes[0]
      }
      choosedIndexes.push(maxIndex);
    }
    
    const players = [];
    choosedIndexes.forEach((choosed, index) => {
      switch(choosed) {
          case 0:
            players.push(g1[index])
            break;
          case 1:
            players.push(g2[index])
            break;
           case 2:
            players.push(f1[index])
            break; 
            case 3:
            players.push(f2[index])
            break; 
           case 4:
            players.push(y1[index])
            break; 
      }
    })
    
    console.log(players);
    
    console.log(players.reduce((prev, next) => {
      return prev + next
    }, 0));
```